# PSPDFKit upgrade

Tags: objective-c, pspdfkit

I am upgrading PSPDFKit to the latest version but I am having issues with some methods that were changed.
I looked in the changelog but not luck, and the documentation is not that good yet.

I have the following code

```
[pdfController.emailButtonItem  setSendOptions:PSPDFDocumentSharingOptionCurrentPageOnly|PSPDFDocumentSharingOptionAllPages|PSPDFDocumentSharingOptionFlattenAnnotations|PSPDFDocumentSharingOptionEmbedAnnotations];
```

That I want to make it work with the latest version.
I have seen that in the new version I have to so something like:

```
PSPDFDocumentSharingViewController *sharingVC = [[PSPDFDocumentSharingViewController alloc] initWithDocument:document visiblePages:nil allowedSharingOptions:PSPDFDocumentSharingOptionCurrentPageOnly|PSPDFDocumentSharingOptionAllPages|PSPDFDocumentSharingOptionFlattenAnnotations|PSPDFDocumentSharingOptionEmbedAnnotations];
```

but I don´t know how to apply that to my PSPDFViewController object (pdfController).

Also I would like to know how to move this to the new version:

pdfController.emailButtonItem.mailComposeViewControllerCustomizationBlock = ^(MFMailComposeViewController *mailController) {
                    [mailController setSubject:@"Information"];
                };

I have seen this in the documentation:

API: Removes the mailComposeViewControllerCustomizationBlock. Use the pdfViewController:shouldShowController:embeddedInController:options: delegate.

But no idea how to apply it.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In general, https://support.pspdfkit.com is the preferred way for us to give support.

In your case, this property now lives in `PSPDFConfiguration`:
https://pspdfkit.com/api/ios/Classes/PSPDFConfiguration.html#//api/name/mailSharingOptions

Comment: I agree that users shouldn't expect support here, but it sure makes life much easier for other people who have the same issue